# Gradient fill in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, graphics, gdi+

Why in the world would the following simple code fail? This code always fills the path with the gradient from left to right, no matter which value of LinearGradientMode I use. graphPath is a GraphicPath object created elsewhere (basically a rounded rectangle):

```
Dim gradBrush as New LinearGradientBrush(rect, color1, color2, LinearGradientMode.Vertical)
graphics.FillPath(gradBrush, graphPath)
```

### UPDATE

To everyone's wonder, even this fails (draws horizontally). Simply create a new VB.NET WinForms project and paste the following code in Form1's Paint event:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
    Dim gradBrush As New LinearGradientBrush(Me.ClientRectangle, Color.Red, Color.White, LinearGradientMode.BackwardDiagonal)
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(gradBrush, Me.ClientRectangle)
  End Sub
```

So I don't think this has anything to do with the path construction.

### NOTE

I'll be glad if someone could just confirm this issue happens on their machines too, so that we know it is something with GDI+ and not my code. Just for reference, I have tried it on a WinXP VM and Win7 machine (32-bit, Aero mode) with .NET Fx 4.0 Client Profile and Full version.

## FINALLY

First of all, thanks to all the great folks who helped me discover it. The problem was that I was editing someone else's code who had created an enum named exactly LinearGradientMode (to support the None option that he needed for his purpose). Now when he sent the object of this enum to LinearGradientBrush's constructor, C# compiler would think that the closest matching overload was the one that take "angle" parameter (this is my theory), and would convert the value of my gradient mode to equivalent int (0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 are the values) and call that constructor, resulting in a (nearly) horizontal gradient in each case.

Thanks again to everyone who participated.

Comment: What is contained in `rect`?  The Win32 documentation states that the rectangle provided can affect the direction of the gradient.

Comment: rect simply is the "container" area that defines the rounded rectangle shape.

Comment: How are you creating the path?

Comment: Okay, the example code you pasted works fine for me. (I *am* on Mono, though.) Is your .NET okay? :D

Comment: No luck on my side. I went as far as checking if it was really a problem with .NET Fx on my machine and tested it on an XP VM and got the same results. The next step is to check my system mainboard. ;-)

Comment: It would probably help if you posted an image of what the rectangle should look like.  Your example has one example as mode Vertical and the other BackwardDiagonal.  In your posted answer, where are you getting LinearGradientMode.None?  None isn't one of my options.

Comment: Not sure if I fully grasped what you're saying, but it really doesn't matter what rectangle you choose. See the simplest Paint example above. About LinearGradientMode.None option, in my scenario, I'm handling it the same way I'm handling Vertical mode. But since this can be different for different users, I left that piece out.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your rectangle has been added to the GraphicsPath.

Comment: a GraphicsPath must contain the rectangle it is to fill - so adding it is imperative. [GP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6sck65w.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have worked around the issue (bug?) by manually creating the start and end points for each gradient mode and then using the Two-Points overload of the constructor. Here's the code if someone may be interested:

```
  Dim st, en As Point
  Select Case mGradientMode
      Case LinearGradientMode.Vertical
        st = New Point(CInt(rect.X + rect.Width / 2), rect.Y)
        en = New Point(CInt(rect.X + rect.Width / 2), rect.Bottom)
      Case LinearGradientMode.Horizontal
        st = New Point(rect.X, CInt(rect.Y + rect.Height / 2))
        en = New Point(rect.Right, CInt(rect.Y + rect.Height / 2))
      Case LinearGradientMode.ForwardDiagonal
        st = rect.Location
        en = New Point(rect.Right, rect.Bottom)
      Case LinearGradientMode.BackwardDiagonal
        st = New Point(rect.Right, rect.Bottom)
        en = rect.Location
  End Select

  If Me.mGradientMode = LinearGradientMode.None Then
      gradBrush = New LinearGradientBrush(st, en, color1, color1)
  Else
      gradBrush = New LinearGradientBrush(st, en, color1, color2)
  End If
```

I'll wait for more input before marking this as answer.

Comment: This is not an answer.  It does not explain why the brush misbehaves on your machine.

Comment: Somehow I happen to agree with you :). I will wait for a better candidate for being marked as answer.

Comment: @dotNET Your code here shouldn't compile because there is no "None" member for the LinearGradientMode enum.  BTW, use the @ and the user name to send that user a notification through comments.

Comment: @LarsTech: I *think* post owners' comments are directed to the last commenter.

Comment: @minitech It seems to be anyone in the comment tree, er, list.  I sort of combined two comments into one because the OP was also making comments at users (me) from their question post without directing it at them.

Comment: Oh... did you make your *own* `LinearGradientMode` enumeration, then? That could wreak some havoc.

Comment: @LarsTech: Thanks a ton for that notification tip.

Comment: @minitech: Thanks heaps man. I couldn't have discovered this on my own. See my explanation above. I wish I could somehow mark these comments as answer.

Answer (score 0):

test this code:

```
Me.CreateGraphics.FillRectangle(New Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(Me.ClientRectangle, Color.Blue, Color.Black, Drawing2D.LinearGradientMode.BackwardDiagonal), Me.ClientRectangle)
```